# How can I make the new Podcasts app update iTunes played status?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, podcasts, podcasts.app

I currently have iTunes set to sync all unplayed episodes of all podcasts to my iPhone.  (I'm a bit behind - there are nearly 70 of them.)  Today I downloaded Apple's new Podcasts app, and was pleased to find that it "picked up" the podcasts that were already on the iPhone.  I have listened to a few podcasts today, and just now synced to my Mac (twice).  I was disappointed to find that the podcasts I had listened to were not marked as played, either in iTunes on the Mac, or in the stock Music app, and therefore not removed from the phone.

I can't seem to find any settings for the Podcasts app - either in the app or in the Settings app - that might affect this behaviour.  Is there anything I can do to make the Podcasts app update the played status in the Music app or in iTunes without manually marking them as played or scrubbing through them?

Comment: I was as disappointed as you were to find that there's no apparent sync between Podcast subscriptions nor played/unplayed status back to the desktop iTunes, even when both accounts are signed in under the same AppleID and have iCloud enabled. I started a thread over on the Apple Support Forums about it, hope it gets some attention over there:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4061461

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz thanks, I wanted to add that tag originally but I don't have enough rep over here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded to iOS 6 yesterday, and it seems that this has been resolved itself, either through updates to iTunes or Podcasts.app (or both).

When I sync with my Mac, the podcasts I had listened to in Podcasts.app were correctly marked as played in iTunes.  Yay!

Comment: Did you sync over WiFI or USB?

Comment: Both, I've since deleted Podcasts.app and gone back to the Music app because Podcasts.app is (censored)...